# What are commonly used methods to represent a document by a vector?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, information-retrieval, language-models

Methods that I know of

- Bag of words + weighting: tf-idf, bm25
- Topic models: LSA, LDA
- Word/sentence/document embedding

Are there other commonly used methods to represent a document by a vector?

Comment: LSTM Autoencoders.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from unsupervised methods like doc2vec, there are couple of supervised methods:

- Siamese network: [github example](https://github.com/dhwajraj/deep-siamese-text-similarity), [What are Siamese neural networks](https://www.quora.com/What-are-Siamese-neural-networks-what-applications-are-they-good-for-and-why)
- [DSSM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/dssm/)
- [StarSpace](https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace#sentencespace-learning-sentence-embeddings)

All of them aims to create vector representations for documents, so dot product of vectors would represent semantically similar of documents.

Comment: Please include explanation and context for links. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

In the topic models category there is also NMF (Non-negative matrix factorization)